# Gridlayout background adjustment

Tags: android

How to adjust background accurately for gridlayout? I have a gridlayout of 6x6 and the background should be on exact locations.  It appears differently on different devices.

Comment: can you able to provide what you mean by 'background accurately ' and 'appears differently on different devices'

Comment: Use `weights` to adjust elements/views in gridlayout symmetrically.

If required, `add 2 dummy views` (1 each on left and right) with some weight in proportion to the weight of the individual elements/views.

And assign `total weight` to the gridlayout.

Comment: @Sree its like i have a table and an image of circles for each location. i want each circle to be right behind cell location but the image appears moved in different mobile devices no matter how i adjust it.

Comment: better you use a grid and in adapter you can set the back image and cell location which will work as you are looking

Comment: Then the items can have it as a background. If the background is so dependent on the items, it should be a part of item's background.

Answer (score 0):

For better user experience and effective output, I would suggest you to go for RecyclerView . You can not only adjust the view sizes as well as block sizes,but also can have access to so many other advanced features.It works exactly as GridView anyway but in a more better way.

Comment: i am using Gridlayout. Will it work same for gridlayout too?

Comment: See even I was using GridView before in my project , but I was unable to get the required output using GridView .So I used RecyclerView .You will get the output exactly the way you want.same happens with gridlayout I hope.